# promtool unit test not showing expected results

Tags: prometheus

I need help in this alert test.
This is the alert rule I have,

```yaml
- alert: MemoryUsage90Percent
  expr: sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{job="cadvisor",container_label_io_rancher_stack_name!="", image=~"rancher.*"}) by (container_label_io_rancher_stack_name, instance, dns_name) /1024/1024/1024 *100 > 90
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: Critical
    alert_owner: alerts-infra
  annotations:
    description: "Service memory has been at over 90% for 1 minute. Service: {{ $labels.container_label_io_rancher_stack_name }}, DnsName: {{ $labels.dns_name }}. \n"
```

I am trying to write a test for this,
tests:

```yaml
# Infra Alert Tests
- input_series:
    - series: 'container_memory_usage_bytes{job="cadvisor",container_label_io_rancher_stack_name="network-service",image="rancher.test"}'
      values: '0 100000000 0 100000000 100000000'
  alert_rule_test:
    - alertname: MemoryUsage90Percent
     # eval_time: 5m
      exp_alerts:
        - exp_labels:
            alertname: MemoryUsage90Percent
            severity: Critical
            alert_owner: alerts-infra
          exp_annotations:
            description: "Service memory has been at over 90% for 1 minute. Service: (), DnsName: ()."
```

But I am always getting ,

```
Unit Testing:  tests/infra_db_alerts-tests.yml
  FAILED:
    alertname: ServiceMemoryUsage90Percent, time: 0s,
        exp:[
            0:
              Labels:{alert_owner="alerts-infra", alertname="ServiceMemoryUsage90Percent", severity="Critical"}
              Annotations:{description="Service memory has been at over 90% for 1 minute. Service: (), DnsName: ()."}
            ],
        got:[]
```

I tried many options in alert rule testing. But nothing helped.
Any help on this please?
not sure why I am getting got as empty. And always alert is getting triggered even if I keep input series value as 0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with alert testing, but I will guess that it's somehow connected to the following math: `100000000 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 * 100 ~= 9.313`, <90.

Comment: yeah..the result is < 90. then why is it triggering the alert?

Comment: It is not triggering alert. Your `got` array is empty. But you specified alert as expected. As a result your test fails.

Comment: Thankyou :) With this change   - input_series:
      - series: 'container_memory_usage_bytes{job="cadvisor",container_label_io_rancher_stack_name="network-service",image="rancher.test"}'
        values: '1000000000 0 0 1000000000 1000000000'
I am able to get the result in got: []

Comment: However, if I want to show as Success and not as failed, what should I do?
I dont want even empty got: []. I just want to show as success when there is no alert scenario.But this alert is always throwing for me with got: [] when the value is less than 90

Comment: Then you should leave `exp_alerts` empty. [Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/#alert_test_case) is always good place to start.

Comment: I added similar configuration with exp_alerts empty. 
    alert_rule_test:
      # Node Status Tests
      - alertname: RabbitMQNodeDown
        eval_time: 30s
        exp_alerts: []

      - alertname: RabbitMQNodeDown
        eval_time: 1m
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              alertname: RabbitMQNodeDown
              severity: Critical
              alert_owner: alerts-infra
            exp_annotations:
              description: "RabbitMQ\nINSTANCE: ()\nNODE: () has been down for more than 1 minute"

The above config is not triggering alert.

Comment: I added similar config as mentioned in above comment..but mine is still triggering alert with got: [0]. The RabbitMQ one is showing as Success. What could be the difference?

Comment: Since this is separate issue, I recommend you delete this question. Thoroughly explore documentation and manuals on matter, and if problem will persist with you knew knowledge, create new question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer.
Its because , the labels and annotations didnt match in the expected and got results. Once I fixed it, everything worked fine.